# What do cylinder and path objects (and more generally, homotopies) look like in Ch(R)?

Tags: homological-algebra, model-categories

Let $Ch(R)$, the category of $R$-module chain complexes indexed by $\mathbb{Z}$, be endowed with the usual model structure (i.e., weak equivalences produce homology isomorphisms and fibrations are just the surjections).

Recall that a cylinder object for an object $X$ is a factoring of the fold map $X\amalg X \to X$ into a composition
$$ X=X\amalg X \overset{i \amalg j}\to X' \overset{f}\to X $$
such that $i\amalg j$ is a cofibration and $f$ is a weak equivalence. Similarly, a path object factors the diagonal map $X\to X\times X$ into a weak equivalence and a fibration.

In a category of nice spaces, a cylinder object is the product space $X\times I$, whilst the path object is the mapping space $X^I$.

By analogy with this, I would think that logical choices for a cylinder chain for a chain $M$ would be $M\otimes R$, where $R$ is the ring $R$ in every degree and has zero maps as the boundaries. Similarly, I'd think some kind of chain of modules of maps would be a correct path chain, but I'm not feeling I can prove the axioms on the maps in and out of it.

My question: what do these objects look like in $Ch(R)$, given a chain $M$? Is there an intuitive analogy with what they are in the category of nice spaces?

Comment: A standard model for the interval $I$ has $R\oplus R$ in degree zero (the endpoints of the interval) and $R$ in degree $1$ (the interval itself) with the differential of the degree one element the difference of the two degree zero elements. Then you can use $I$ as your interval and have your cylinder $X\otimes I$ and path object $X^I$ (the chain complex of linear, not-necessarily degree preserving maps) as you suggest.

Comment: One model for these objects comes from the "tensoring" of chain complexes over spaces, given by $$(M,X) \mapsto M \otimes_R C_* (X),$$
where "$C_*(X)$" means, for instance, the simplicial chains on a simplicial model of X (or whatever you feel like using to build the ordinary homology of X). For $X=[0,1]$, you might take $$C_*([0, 1]) = \{R\oplus R \xleftarrow{(1, -1)} R\},$$ so that $M\otimes I$ looks like the model for the cylinder object that Gabriel quotes. There's something similar for "cotensoring" and path objects, and this can also motivate the definition of chain homotopy.)

Comment: @GabrielC.Drummond-Cole What is $X^I$, as a chain complex? It is clear that the $n$th module is $X_{n}^{I_n}$, the module of linear maps, but what are the boundary maps?

Comment: Doesn't Hovey's book (chapter 2) answer your question?

Comment: In general, you get a differential on $Maps(V,W)$ by commuting with the differentials of $V$ and $W$: $d(f) = d_W\circ f + (-1)^{|f|} f\circ d_V$.

Comment: I would recommend to read Kamps and Porter, Abstract Homotopy and Simple Homotopy Theory, World Scientific, Chap. III, §3.